# media screen and min-width 600px not working

Tags: html, css

I put these links in header, but not working with estilos.mobile.cc :( why?????

> link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 600px)" >href="http://www.xxxxxx.es/static/css/estilos.mobile.css"  />
>
> link href="http://www.xxxxxx.es/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >media="screen">
>
> link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.xxxxxxx.es/static>
>
> /css/estilos.css" />

I tried to put differents options and not working!!! :(

> media=screen and (min-width: 600px)
>
> media="(min-width: 600px)"
>
> media=(min-width: 600px)
>
> media='screen and (min-width: 600px)'

And still not working.... please help me

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. what browser are you using?

Comment: What's the > sign is doing in the reference? E.g. link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 600px)" >href="http://www.xxxxxx.es/static/css/estilos.mobile.css" /> Is it a typo?

Comment: Please copy-paste the actual code and use code formatting (the `{}` button in the editor) to format it, not quote formatting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My apologies but I have no idea what type of syntax that is. in your case you just need to do two things :
first add this in your css file

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    h2 { font-size: 2.2em; }
    /*or anything you want to do*/ 
}
```

second : add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

to your head

cheers!

Comment: The problem is not catch the estilos.mobile.css I don't know why!

Comment: which platform are you using ? If you are using ruby on rails make sure to put the stylesheet in public/assets folder. Or if you are working on rails 4.0.0 then you can directly include the stylesheet as <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.mobile.css">
You dont need to provide the full link to the stylesheet file.

Comment: Syntax for my css was fine. The second tag with meta was the issue.